# Django orm filtering by month or day doesn't work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I am using PostgreSQL for development. I need to filter some model by day so that I write that orm method.

```py
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()

today_count = Count(
   "id",
   filter=Q(
       created_at__year=now.year,
       created_at__month=now.month,
       created_at__day=now.day,
   ),
   )
   Model.objects.aggregate(today=today_count)
```

Also, I set USE_TZ to True in settings.
This code works correctly with PostgreSQL but since we are using MySql on production, Always today_count returns 0. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Have you tried it with a direct date query?

filter=Q(created_at__date=now.date())

Answer (score 0):

The 3 seperate filters for year, month, and day just seems a little weird. Have you tried filtering like this? This is how the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#date) do it.

```
filter=Q(created_at__date=datetime.date(now.year, now.month, now.day)),
```

Comment: What if I need filter by week or month? For example filter(created_at__month=now.month, created_at__year=now.year) this is works, how can I write with date lookup ?